# ajax_deliver returns json instead of content

Tags: ajax

I have a panel with two columns. In the left is a views with teasers, in the right the full body text of a node.
If you click on a link in the views the content in the right panel should be replaced with the body text (and images).
Here the code of the module:

```
<?php
function customNews_menu() {
        $items['customNews/%/%node'] = array(
                'access arguments' => array('access content'),
                'page callback' => 'customNews_ajax_callback',
                'access callback' => 'user_access',
                'page arguments' => array(1,2),
                'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        );
        return $items;
}

function customNews_ajax_callback($js, $node) {
    if ($js == 'nojs') {
        drupal_goto('node/' . $node->nid);
    }
        $div_id = 'customNewsContent';
        $vnode = node_view($node);
        $vnode['is_ajax'] = true;
        $output = '<div class="panel-pane pane-node" id="'.$div_id.'">'.theme("node", $vnode).'</div>';
        $commands = array();
        $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#'.$div_id, $output);
        $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
        ajax_deliver($page);
}
?>
```

When I run it I get the following back in the browser:

```
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/drupal\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"seeleben","theme_token":"wdFHgqik_Sx4kvKrKXtT9tAndWxYgNr2-cO6lfT09gg"},"colorbox":{"opacity":"0.85","current":"{current} of {total}","previous":"\u00ab Prev","next":"Next \u00bb","close":"Schlie\u00dfen","maxWidth":"98%","maxHeight":"98%","fixed":true,"mobiledetect":true,"mobiledevicewidth":"480px"}},"merge":true},.........
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

***You are almost there!***

1. You are opening a serious security hole in your site, allowing anyone who has `access content` permission to access all nodes bypassing node access system.

Assuming you need to use ctools's Ajax framework extension, you obviously need to have ctools module enabled.

**1. Change your menu loader to this:**

`$items['customNews/%ctools_js/%node']`

This will make Drupal pass the second %ctools_js argument to ctools_js_load function that returns TRUE if `nojs` was changed to `ajax`.

**2. The link.**

Ctools won't change all "nojs" occurrences in the page. You need to create a special link using `ctools_ajax_text_button` function, or by adding classes to the link.

```
<?php 
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_modal_add_js();
  print ctools_ajax_text_button(t('Read more'), 'customNews/nojs/1'); //1 is the node ID. Replace accordingly. You need to use "nojs" here. 
?>
```

**3. Almost there!**

Your code should work now. However, make sure you have proper node access checks before showing anything. `SA-CORE-2-14-005` was touch enough.

```
if ($js == 'nojs') {
        drupal_goto('node/' . $node->nid);
    }
```

Can be changed to:

```
if (!$js) {
  drupal_goto('node/' . $node->nid);
}
```

The importance of this "special link" is that ctools's JS registers all anchor tags in `Drupal.ajax` that follows the class name convention. For my own use, I have a small function that returns the proper link so I don't have to include ctools's `ajax.inc` file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can't bring it to work.
As I said I have a panel with two columns. In the left I have the views, where I want to click on the link 'read more' and then the whole content should be shown in the right panel. I don't see how to bring your php-code into the views link.

When I make a node.tpl.php file (without panel) I can put the code in and by clicking on the link i see, the ajax spinner, but because I don't have the second panel nothing is shown.

When I use the same node within the panel the Ajax don't work anymore. Don't know what stops is.